# What programs could I use to render an animation based on points ("atoms") rather than models?

Tags: 3d, animation, rendering, voxels

I've rendered the following animation using JavaScript and canvas:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMLqe5HdVok

For that, I used points exclusively - i.e., there is no mesh/trigs, not only the photons, but the geometry of the prism itself is made out of tons of small atoms. I then projected each atom to screen, ordered by depth and blended transparencies. I really like this atom-based rendering strategy, because it is very flexible, allowing me to create all sort of crazy geometries procedurally easily; doing the same for meshes would be hard. Obviously, this is way too slow on JavaScript/canvas, so it isn't really practical. I could do it with WebGL, but that'd be a lot of work.

Are there game engines and/or 3D software that I could use to make this kind of rendering strategy possible in an actual game? What exactly am I looking for? Is this a known pattern/feature? Keywords and references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Media Molecule's "Dreams" uses point clouds to render their game content, authored using signed distance fields. So, there are applications in games currently. In less specialized tech, like an out of the box engine, you may be able to achieve this using particle system features. Requests for engine/software recommendations are considered off-topic on this site, but if you narrow down the tech/platform you want to use, you may be able to rephrase your question as "how do I achieve this effect?" rather than "what tool should I use?"

Comment: @DMGregory the problem is that I know exactly how to achieve this effect, but I don't want to program it all myself. I tried to ask something along the lines of "what are keywords related to that technique"; that way I can google for particular tools (which will have those keywords on their sites) without actually asking for them here.

Answer (score 1):

This technique in general is known as [Volume Rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_rendering).

Most games use mesh rendering because it is very efficient in most use cases, but there are weaknesses, for example sculpting/carving, or representing very complex surfaces. In these few cases, volume rendering offers an alternative.

Volume rendering is mostly used outside games, because it's typically much more expensive. You find it in medical imaging, various scientific fields, where the graphics hardware is workstation-class or the rendering is non-real-time. So most volume rendering software is going to be too slow to do real-time games on commodity computer hardware.

Instead, the most common type of volume rendering you see in real games today is voxels, or blocks ala Minecraft. These games use a simple shape (e.g. a cube) that's used repeatedly to build complex shapes. With [instancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_instancing), this technique is not that inefficient, but there are still hard problems, like culling, that make it much less efficient than regular surface meshes. This is why games that use voxels look so blocky - they must use large blocks otherwise the rendering will be too expensive.

One advantage with volume rendering is that it's very simple to do level-of-detail. A number of years back some people were talking about a solution called "Unlimited Detail". But there are a number of fundamental limitations with this approach that make it unsuitable for games.